# C# List all methods in a control

Tags: c#, reflection, user-controls

I apologize if this has been asked and answered before but I was not able to find an answer.

I know how to walk through the controls collection and get a listing of all the controls including child controls.

```
    void printControlTree(Control ctl, int indent)
    {
      string pad = "";
      for(int i=0; i < indent; i++)
      {
        pad += "   ";
      }

      Print(pad + "=> " + ctl.Name);

      if (ctl.Controls != null && ctl.Controls.Count > 0)
      {
        foreach (Control c in ctl.Controls)
        {
            printControlTree(c, indent+1);
        }
      }
     }
```

What I'd like to do is to also get a listing of ALL the methods in each control and child control. Is this possible? I would think so as there is the Control.ControlCollection.Find method to find a specific method in a control by name, but I want a listing of all the methods without knowing their names ahead of time. Also, is it possible to get a listing of everything in a control: methods, input fields, etc.? Your help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "methods"?

Comment: Look into reflection.

Comment: See [Reflection in the .NET Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7ykdhsy.aspx)

Comment: I would suggest also learning how to format your code so that it's readable just a good suggestion.

Comment: Hm.  Yea..reflection does these types of operations...but this question covers far too much ground.  It is not answerable.

Comment: I think you ned to know the name first. Do you not?

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey: In what way does it cover too much ground?

Comment: @PBrenek#1: Wrong.  `control.GetType().GetMethods()`.

Comment: @DJ KRAZE: I am not what specifically you mean. Can you please let me know for future reference? Thank you.

Comment: @SLaks: Thank you. Type.GetMethods() seems promising. I will look into this.

Comment: Pbrenk I will edit your code and show you and perhaps you will understand what I am talking about.. it's all about readability

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
static void PrintMethods(Object o) {

    Type t = o.GetType();
    MethodInfo[] methods = t.GetMethods();
    foreach(MethodInfo method in methods) {

        Print( method.Name );
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

First we'll start with a method that returns all of the child controls of a control (recursively) rather than just printing them.

```
public static IEnumerable<Control> GetAllControls(Control control)
{
    Stack<Control> stack = new Stack<Control>();
    stack.Push(control);

    while (stack.Any())
    {
        var next = stack.Pop();
        yield return next;
        foreach (var child in next.Controls.OfType<Control>())
        {
            stack.Push(child);
        }
    }
}
```

Next we'll write a method that, given a sequence of objects, transforms it into a sequence of all of the methods of all of those objects:

```
public static IEnumerable<MethodInfo> GetMethods<T>(IEnumerable<T> sequence)
{
    return sequence.GroupBy(obj => obj.GetType())
        .SelectMany(group => group.Key.GetMethods());
}
```

Now we just call them:

```
foreach(var methodInfo in GetMethods(GetAllControls(someControl))
{
    //print method name
}
```

If you think you'll use these methods enough you may want to convert them to extension methods.

Comment: Tried this but got an error: The non-generic type 'System.Collections.IEnumerable' cannot be used with type arguments CS0308 Fixed it by using Collections.Generic but had another slew of errors.

Comment: @PBrenek You need a `using System.Collection.Generic`.

Comment: @PBrenek You'll also need a using for `System.Linq`, and `System.Reflection`.

Comment: Error: Argument '1': cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Windows.Forms.Control>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<object>' CS1503

Comment: @PBrenek This will only work with .NET 4.0, in which generic covariance is added.  With 3.5 you'd need to add `.Cast<object>()` to the result of `GetAllControls`, or make `GetAllControls` generic.

Comment: Not sure where to add the cast or how to convert GetAllControls to generic.

Comment: @PBrenek It's as simple as adding a generic parameter and using it for the sequence.  I edited it in.  As for `Cast`, if you wanted to use that instead, as I said before, you just need to call it on the result of `GetAllControls`.  Add `Cast<object>()` to the return value of that method.

Comment: Thank you. This compiled. Pardon me for being this stupid but this approach is unfamiliar and very new to me. How would I now print the information gathered? Thank you.

Comment: @PBrenek You would print it where the `//print method name` comment is shown.

Comment: @PBrenek First off, "didn't work" is basically useless.  Did it not compile, if so, what was the error?  Did you get unexpected output, if so, what did you expect, and what did you get?  In this case, the method info is a type that contains a lot of information about the method, and you need to decide what to print.  You may want to print the `Name`, you may want to print the `DeclaringType`, or any one of the several dozen other properties.  The point is that at that point you have enough info to come up with whatever it is that you need.

Comment: The program compiled. When I ran it, trying to print the name, I get no output - nothing printed. You have been very helpful. Thank you. I will work on it.

Comment: I think your 'GetAllControls method is broken: you don't push the initial 'Control on the stack ... so I assume it will always return an empty IEnumerable.

Answer (score -1):

You can find examples of listing a class' members here:

[Viewing Type Information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t0cs7xez.aspx)

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;

class Mymemberinfo
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine ("\nReflection.MemberInfo");
        // Gets the Type and MemberInfo.
        Type MyType = Type.GetType("System.IO.File");
        MemberInfo[] Mymemberinfoarray = MyType.GetMembers();
        // Gets and displays the DeclaringType method.
        Console.WriteLine("\nThere are {0} members in {1}.",
            Mymemberinfoarray.Length, MyType.FullName);
        Console.WriteLine("{0}.", MyType.FullName);
        if (MyType.IsPublic)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} is public.", MyType.FullName);
        }
    }
}
```

If you already have an object (such as a control), you can circumvent some of the above code like so:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;

class Mymemberinfo
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        // Whatever kind of control you are using:
        Object l_control = new Object();

        Console.WriteLine ("\nReflection.MemberInfo");
        // Gets the Type and MemberInfo.

        // ----- Call l_control.GetType();
        Type MyType = l_control.GetType();
        MemberInfo[] Mymemberinfoarray = MyType.GetMembers();
        // Gets and displays the DeclaringType method.
        Console.WriteLine("\nThere are {0} members in {1}.",
            Mymemberinfoarray.Length, MyType.FullName);
        Console.WriteLine("{0}.", MyType.FullName);
        if (MyType.IsPublic)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} is public.", MyType.FullName);
        }
    }
}
```

You can read more about Reflection on the MSDN website:

[Reflection in the .NET Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7ykdhsy.aspx)

The articles on MSDN include complete descriptions and example of how to use each feature.

Comment: This gets the members. Thank you.